# KendoUI grouped filters

Tags: javascript, filter, kendo-ui, grid

I'm trying to make grouped filters for KendoUI grid. I have to create a text field that filters the grid by name and a kendo numeric field that filters grid by Units in stock.

How could I make grouped filters?

I tried the following but it's not working - bad request 404 error:

```js
$('body').bind('keyup mouseup', '#UnitsInStock', function () {
  var value = $('#UnitsInStock').val();
  var val = $('#ProductName').val();


  if (value) {
    grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter(myFilters(val, value));
  } else {
    grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter();
  }

});

function myFilters(name='', price='') {


  var filters = {
    logic: "or",
    filters: [
      { field: "ProductName", operator: "startswith", value: name},
      { field: "UnitsInStock", operator: "gte", value: price}
    ]                                        


  }
  return filters;

}
```

```html
<div id="grid"></div>
  <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
       <div class="toolbar">
      <label for="category">Search by Product Name:</label>
      <input type="search" id="ProductName" />
       <input id="UnitsInStock"  type="number" />
    </div>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have fields to be filtered on of multiple types, make sure the types are preserved when creating the filter object. for example, you could predefined your filter fields as such..

```
var filterFields = [{ field: "Units", type: "number" }, { field: "Name", type: "string" }]
```

and get the user input

```
var searchString = // user input
```

and a method to generate the filters similar to this

```
var getFilter = function (filterFields, searchString) {
        var filterInt = function (value) {
            if (/^(\-|\+)?([0-9]+|Infinity)$/.test(value))
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        var filters = [];
        var i = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < filterFields.length; i++) {
            if (filterFields[i].type === "string") {
                filters.push({
                    field: filterFields[i].field,
                    operator: "startswith",
                    value: searchString.toString()
                });
            }
            if (filterFields[i].type === "number") {
                if (filterInt(searchString)) {
                    filters.push({
                        field: filterFields[i].field,
                        operator: "gte",
                        value: parseInt(searchString)
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        return {
            logic: "or",
            filters: filters
        };
    }
```

finally, filter your grid

```
grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter(getFilter(filterFields, searchString))
```

also, to be certain that your endpoint works, use a tool such as postman and do a GET (`http://............./Units?$filter=Id eq 1 and Name eq 'name'`).